# Understanding portable music player's power specs

Tags: power, amplifier

Right now I'm looking at the specs of two portable music players. The specs of the first player describe the power provied to the headphones, depending on their impedance:

- Output into 16 Ohm - > 436 mW
- Output into 32 Ohm - > 255 mW
- Output into 300 Ohm - > 27 mW
- Max output voltage - >8.2 Vp-p
- Max output current - >250 mA

and the second one:

- Output into 16 Ohm - > 460 mW
- Output into 32 Ohm - > 255 mW
- Output into 300 Ohm - > 28 mW
- Max output voltage - >8 Vp-p
- Max output current - >150 mA

Is it physically possible for both these specs to be true? What might be a possible logical explanation of this?

For me it pretty much conflicts with the Ohm law. Look at the first player - it has both higher maximum voltage and current (limited by battery source), but somehow it produces less power than the second one. Power is not something that magically appears on a cable, but it's directly dependent on the voltage and load - impedance of headphones in this case (and maximum output current the battery can handle).

I know that my question is not related to circuit deisgning, but I guess it can give a better understanding of certain aspects for beginners.

Comment: Actually calculating them out will show that the available voltage and current easily exceeds all of the claimed output power levels, with the solitary exception of 460 mW into 16 ohms using only 150 mA.  However, the 150 mA is an "at least", not an "at most".  The power levels may also be thermal ratings rather than peak limits.

Comment: @ChrisStratton actually, why would anyone limit the maximum current output from the battery of a device? To prevent overheating?

Comment: How would **YOU** justify that there is any anomaly in the specs - you show an anomaly and someone will give an explanation - you need to be more proactive and not just expect open-ended questions to be solved. Also, don't mix typical numbers with max or min numbers - that's your likely problem.

Comment: @Andyaka I think I've described the anomaly quite clearly: [the first player] it has both higher maximum voltage and current (limited by battery source), but somehow it produces less power than the second one.

Comment: READ what I said - don't compare max values with non-max values - it just doesn't stack up.

Answer (score 1):

Those specifications are quite close. There are a few things to bear in mind though. They don't state what the levels of distortion are for the readings. If you imagine one using a pure sine-wave and basing their measurements on that and the other driving theirs into clipping slightly then the second will get more power but at worse distortion.

Now let's calculate power. If the amplifier can give out 8 V peak to peak then that's 4 V peak and, dividing by root 2 to get the true RMS, that works out as 2.83 Vrms. Now multiply this by 0.15 A and we get 0.424 W = 424 mW - pretty close to the specs. Chances are they're both using the same chip!

But, I hear you say, what about the 250 mA max current on the first unit? Well we don't know for sure. Note that they're not saying it will supply 250 mA at full voltage. I'd be inclined to believe the second unit's specs.

Mind your ears. :^)